# Вызов метода класса со свойствами класса

Tags: php, классы

Скажем, есть сласс:

```
class userclass{
public $var1;
public $var2; 

public function myfunc($var1,$var2){
$summ = $var1+$var2;
return $summ;
}
}
```

Теперь нужно вызвать метод `myfunc` со свойствами `var1` и `var2` без явного назначения значений.

`$calc = new userclass;
$calc->var1 = 10;
$calc->var2 = 120;
$var = $calc->myfunc(); 
/* т.е. что бы строчка выше вызвалась как $var= $calc->myfunc(10,120); */`

Реально ли как то так извернуться, избегая глобальных переменных?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того объекты и существуют

```
public function myFunc()
{
    return $this->var1 + $this->var2;
}
```

`$this` повзолит вам достучаться до любого свойтсва или метода в разрешенной области видимости (public, protected и private, объявленные в этом классе).

Можно даже так:

```
class Mrjvni
{
    private $a;
    private $b;
    public function __construct($a, $b)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
        $this->b = $b;
    }
    public function myFunc()
    {
        return $this->a + $this->b;
    }
}
```